# С помощью regexp_substr получить число из строки

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql

Есть строки вида:

```
Time 555.55
Time .55
Time 55
```

Надо с помощью `regexp_substr` хочу получить подстроки в виде

```
555.55
.55
55
```

Пробую такое выражение `[[:digit:]]*[\.][[:digit:]]*`
Однако последний вариант не цепляется(цифра без точки)
Если пробую `[[:digit:]]*[\.]?[[:digit:]]*` то вообще ничего не получаю.
Что я делаю не так?
Пример запроса:

```
with n as (
select 'Time 555.55' s from dual
union all
select 'Time .55' from dual
union all
select 'Time 55' from dual
) 
select s, regexp_substr(s, '[[:digit:]]*[\.]?[[:digit:]]*'),  regexp_substr(s, '[[:digit:]]*[\.][[:digit:]]*') from n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае следует использовать квантификатор `+` вместо `*`, указывая обязательное наличие хотя бы одной цифры.

```
'[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]+'
```

Comment: Работает. Но я не понимаю, почему `*` не подходит. Поясните, пожалуйста, в чем подвох?

Comment: @lDrakonl Смотрите, когда вы указываете только `*` или `?` (например, в выражении `'[[:digit:]]*'`) движок regexp проверяет первый символ строки и если он не соответствует паттерну `[[:digit:]]`, считает что совпадение найдено и поиск на этом заканчивается, но это совпадение _пустое_ (не содержит подстроки).

Comment: Понял, спасибо!